# Setting a nullable int to null

Tags: asp.net

In my Appraisal table I've got a field named "AppraisalTrace" which references to another table. This field is an int which can be null because I want to be able to create an Appraisal without an AppraisalTrace. I'm using an xsd to join Database and code.

Now in my code when I'm creating an Appraisal I'm doing the following:

```
oAppraisalRow.SetAppraisalTraceNull();
```

this auto-generated method is provided by the dataRow but it's throwing the following exception when I try to insert an Appraisal with a Null AppraisalTrace:

```
Value for column "AppraisalTrace" in table "Appraisal" is DBNull
```

So how am I supposed to create my Appraisal?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `SetAppraisalTraceNull`? What's the code in it?

Comment: @Oded: That's an autogenerated method of a strongly typed `DataRow` which sets a nullable field to null.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get this exception when you're trying to retrieve the value from the nullable field. Your strongly typed `DataRow` has also an autogenerated `bool` property which indicates if the field is `DBNull` or not. You must use that:

```
if(oAppraisalRow.IsAppraisalTraceNull)
{
    // this causes your exception, so don't access a nullable field directly 
    var trace = oAppraisalRow.AppraisalTrace;
}
else
{   
    // here you can safely get the value
    var trace = oAppraisalRow.AppraisalTrace;
}
```

So check first if the field is null with the `bool` property.

Comment: No, I'm getting this exception when trying to insert an Appraisal with a null AppraisalTrace in the Database

Comment: Is it nullable in the database or have you changed it to be not nullable without refreshing your `TableAdapter` afterwards?

Comment: The TableAdapter has AllowDBNull set to true, the database also allows null. The thing is, NullValue is set as "Throw exception" and can't be set to null nor empty because int can't be null. So how am I supposed to do?

Comment: That's normal, The field does not allow `null` but `DBNull`. The autogenerated `SetAppraisalTraceNull` sets it to `DBNull` which should work. Have you tried to recreate the `TableAdapter`?